# How can I add a paragraph, line break or horizontal rule tag to this code?

Tags: javascript

```
var userChoice = prompt('Choose between Rock,Paper or Scissors');
var computerChoiceArray = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors'];
var choiceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

var compChoice  = computerChoiceArray[choiceNumber];
document.write('Computer chose '+ compChoice)    
    var game = function(compChoice,userChoice) {
        if (compChoice === userChoice) {
            document.write("The result is a Tie!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Rock " && userChoice === "Scissors") {
            document.write("Computer wins !!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Rock " && userChoice === "Paper") {
            document.write("You won !!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Scissors" && userChoice === "Rock") {
            document.write ("You won !!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Scissors" && userChoice === "Paper") {
            document.write("Computer wins !!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Paper" && userChoice === "Rock") {
            document.write("Computer wins !!!")
        }else if( compChoice === "Paper" && userChoice === "Scissors") {
            document.write ("You won !!!")
        }else{
            alert ("Error, "+userChoice+" is not applicable ");
        }
    }

 game(compChoice,userChoice);
```

Even after adding the needed tags there is an error.

Please add any tag for leaving a line or div tag. If possible please suggest some improvements.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you're trying to write any `<p>` or `<br>`...? Also, you'll probably find it easier with proper DOM manipulation rather than `document.write`

Comment: I want to print computer's choice and result each on separate lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code ends up in the error alert is most likely due to the fact that you have spaces added to the text when comparing it, such as `if(userChoice === 'Rock ')` as well as you are ignoring that JavaScript is case sensitive. Meaning `Rock !== 'rock'`

I'm will use your code unchanged as much as possible to ensure it still is your code but please note there is many better ways to write this than comparing string values.

Using `toUpperCase()` allows you to compare the strings regardless if user types `rock` or `rOcK`

You could probably add a `trim()` too as user could choose `Rock` with a space. Consider changing the user choice to a dropdown to eliminate that problem.

In regards to the line-breaks, as you have not specified exactly where, I assume you mean between the text of what the computer chose and the result.

You can add a line break by adding a `<br/>` for example, such as `document.write("<br/>Computer wins !!!")`

> Please note, as other's said using `document.write` is not good,
>   instead try using `document.createElement()` instead. Also, consider
>   changing the user choice to a dropdown to eliminate string issues. You
>   can validate numeric representations of the choices better than
>   comparing strings. I leave that research to you though.

Anyway, the below code is as close to your code as possible with the least amount of changes to get it to match your expected result and fix the error.

```js
var userChoice = prompt('Choose between Rock,Paper or Scissors');
var computerChoiceArray = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var choiceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

var compChoice = computerChoiceArray[choiceNumber];

document.write('Computer chose ' + compChoice);

var game = function(compChoice, userChoice) {
  

  if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === userChoice.toUpperCase()) {
    document.write("<br/>The result is a Tie!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "ROCK" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "SCISSORS") {
    document.write("<br/>Computer wins !!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "ROCK" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "PAPER") {
    document.write("<br/>You won !!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "SCISSORS" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "ROCK") {
    document.write("<br/>You won !!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "SCISSORS" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "PAPER") {
    document.write("<br/>Computer wins !!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "PAPER" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "ROCK") {
    document.write("<br/>Computer wins !!!")
  } else if (compChoice.toUpperCase() === "PAPER" && userChoice.toUpperCase() === "SCISSORS") {
    document.write("<br/>You won !!!")
  } else {
    alert("Error, " + userChoice + " is not applicable ");
  }
}

game(compChoice, userChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code. The main thing which I want to show that you have to split your code to logic parts. In my example there are:

- object `game` which stores all the info
- function `round` which starts a new round and write games logs
- function `writeLogs` which displays the progress.

Note, that this is not the best way to implement this game.

```js
var computerChoiceArray = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
var MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS = 3;

var game = {
  DOMElement: document.getElementById('game-wrapper'),
  roundsCounter: 0,
  logs: []
};

function round(game) {
  if (game.roundsCounter >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS) {
    game.logs.push("The End");
    writeLogs(game);
    return;
  }

  var userChoice = prompt('Choose between: ' + computerChoiceArray.join(', ')) || '';
  userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
  var compChoiceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var compChoice = computerChoiceArray[compChoiceNumber];

  if (compChoice === userChoice) {
    game.logs.push("The result is a Tie!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "rock" && userChoice === "scissors") {
    game.logs.push("Computer wins !!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "rock" && userChoice === "paper") {
    game.logs.push("You won !!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "scissors" && userChoice === "rock") {
    game.logs.push("You won !!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "scissors" && userChoice === "paper") {
    game.logs.push("Computer wins !!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "paper" && userChoice === "rock") {
    game.logs.push("Computer wins !!!");
  } else if (compChoice === "paper" && userChoice === "scissors") {
    game.logs.push("You won !!!");
  } else {
    game.logs.push("Error, " + userChoice + " is not applicable ");
  }
  
  game.roundsCounter += 1;
  writeLogs(game);
  
  // wait a sec to write logs and start a new round
  setTimeout(function() {
   round(game);
  }, 1000)
}

function writeLogs(game) {

  // clear logs
  game.DOMElement.innerHTML = '';
  
  for (var log of game.logs) {
    var logHTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
    logHTMLElement.innerHTML = log;
    game.DOMElement.appendChild(logHTMLElement);
  }
}

// start the first round
round(game);
```

```html
<div id="game-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is a indefinite loop of alert box spam :)

Comment: @Nope You have no choice. It's like Joomanji - you have to finish the game after start :-)

P.S. I've removed the loop)